# Use a GPU to speed up neural net training in R

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, r, gpu

I'm currently training a neural net model in R and am wanting to use a GPU to speed up this process.  I've looked into this but it appears that this is unavailable to Mac users as Apple no longer uses NVIDIA GPUs.

Can anyone tell me if this is the case, and if not how I can go about utilizing a GPU?

Comment: You can always use an external GPU if your current hardware does not support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to convert the code into python, then you could use the [Google colab](http://colab.research.google.com/) environment or [Kaggle kernels](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiohM_w75btAhXZDnIKHatZBToQFjAAegQIARAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kaggle.com%2Fkernels&usg=AOvVaw1kDonuHB2Pn6wcdLjqOcU0). These online platforms provide free GPU's that you can utilize.

Kaggle kernels also [support R directly](https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/27082).

Comment: Am I correct in saying that Kaggle's notebooks don't necessitate translation to Python?

Comment: @BlakeLucey Yes, you are right! I have made the change